# Método 'dinámico' para realizar transacciones de actualización con PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transacciones

Estoy realizando un proyecto web sobre una Gestoría local, en la cual realizan muchísimas transacciones, y estoy utilizando [PDO](http://php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php) para gestionar el acceso a la base de datos en MySQL.

La clase DB se encarga de manera estática de ofrecer acceso a las consultas insert, select, update, delete, procedures y transacciones, pero este último no funciona como lo esperado y me ejecuta la última sentencia preparada con sus parámetros.

Intento que reciba un array de consultas preparadas como strings, y un array de arrays de los parámetros coincidiendo en posición con cada consulta preparada.

> El método de transaction($sqls, $parameters) de la clase DB que falla:

```
public static function transaction($sqls, $parameteres) { // TODO: falla.
    try {
        DB::connect()->beginTransaction();
        foreach (array_combine($sqls, $parameteres) as $sql => $params) {
            $rs = DB::connect()->prepare($sql);
            $rs->execute($params);
        }
        DB::connect()->commit();
        return true;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        print_r($e);
        DB::connect()->rollBack();
        return false;
    }
}
```

**db_config.php**

```
<?php

define("DRIVER_SQL", "mysql");
define("DATABASE", "tests_db");
define("PORT",     "8889");
define("HOSTNAME", "localhost");
define("USERNAME", "root");
define("PASSWORD", "root");


define("URI", DRIVER_SQL . ":dbname=" . DATABASE . ";port=" . PORT . ";host=" . HOSTNAME);

?>
```

**DB.php**

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once('db_config.php');

final class DB {

// STATIC FIELDS....................................................................................................

private static $pdo; // database connection

// SPECIAL METHODS..................................................................................................

final private function __construct() {
    // empty constructor
}

final private function __clone() {
    throw new Exception("You can't clone this object because is unique.");
}

function _destructor() {
    // clean pointer, close database connection
    self::$pdo = null;
}

private static function connect() {
    try {
        if (self::$pdo != null) return self::$pdo;
        self::$pdo = new PDO(URI, USERNAME, PASSWORD, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
        self::$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        self::$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        self::$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, true);
        self::$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, false);
        return self::$pdo;
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo("PDOException: ".$e);
        return false;
    }
}

// STATIC METHODS...................................................................................................

public static function insert($sql, $parameters) {
    return self::_query($sql, $parameters);
}

public static function select($sql, $parameters=null) {
    try {
        $rs = DB::connect()->prepare($sql);
        $rs->execute($parameters);
        return $rs->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        print_r($e);
        return null;
    }
}

public static function update($sql, $parameters) {
    return self::_query($sql, $parameters);
}

public static function delete($sql, $parameters) {
    return self::_query($sql, $parameters);
}

public static function transaction($sqls, $parameteres) { // TODO: falla.
    try {
        DB::connect()->beginTransaction();
        foreach (array_combine($sqls, $parameteres) as $sql => $params) {
            $rs = DB::connect()->prepare($sql);
            $rs->execute($params);
        }
        DB::connect()->commit();
        return true;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        print_r($e);
        DB::connect()->rollBack();
        return false;
    }
}

public static function procedure($sql, $parameters = null) { // TODO: Por testear
    return self::_query($sql, $parameters);
}

private static function _query($sql, $parameters) {
    try {
        $rs = DB::connect()->prepare($sql);
        return $rs->execute($parameters);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        print_r($e);
        return null;
    }
}

}

?>
```

Para realizar las pruebas he utilizado este código:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include_once 'db.php';

// TABLA: id, name, surname, age

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO person VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?)";
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO person VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?)";
$params1 = array('nombre_1', 'apellido_1', '1');
$params2 = array('nombre_2', 'apellido_2', '2');

$sqls = array($sql1,$sql2);
$parameters = array($params1,$params2);

DB::transaction($sqls,$parameters);

foreach (DB::select("SELECT * FROM person") as $row) {
    echo($row['name'] . " " .$row['surname'] . "<br/>");
}

?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema es que `$sql1` y `$sql2` son iguales, por lo que al hacer `array_combine` `$sql1` y `$sql2` pasan a ser la clave del array se unen en una porque no pueden estar repetidos,

Si ejecutas esto:

```
print_r(array_combine($sqls, $parameteres));
```

Verás que tu resultado es:

```
Array
(
    [INSERT INTO person VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?)] => Array
        (
            [0] => nombre_2
            [1] => apellido_2
            [2] => 2
        )

)
```

Es el mismo caso que se describe en la [documentación de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-combine.php)

```
<?php
print_r(array_combine(Array('a','a','b'), Array(1,2,3)));
?>
Returns:
Array
(
    [a] => 2
    [b] => 3
)
```

Por lo tanto, podrías modificar tu método transaction y dejarlo de esta manera:

```
public static function transaction($sqls, $parameteres) { // TODO: falla.
    try {
        DB::connect()->beginTransaction();
        foreach( $sqls as $index => $sql ) {
            $rs = DB::connect()->prepare($sql);
            $rs->execute($parameteres[$index]);
        }
        DB::connect()->commit();
        return true;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        print_r($e);
        DB::connect()->rollBack();
        return false;
    }
}
```